# JSON Deserialization Issue

Tags: jquery, json

I know I'm just missing something stupid here. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/xZvYW/

HTML:

```
<div id="pageheader">
    <h1></h1>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
var si = [{
"courseid": "1",
"coursename": "MISY431/432",
"coursedescription": "Project Management and MIS Projects",
"sectionid": "1",
"sectionname": "",
"semesterid": "1",
"semestername": "Fall 2011",
"semesterstarttimestamp": "9/1/2011 12:00:00 AM",
"phaseid": "3",
"phasename": "Open to Students",
"phasedescription": "Students may view accepted projects and submit project team requests"}];

$("#pageheader h1").html(si.semestername + " " + si.coursename + " " + si.sectionname);
$("#pageheader div").html("Current Phase: <strong>" + si.phasename + "</strong> <em>" + si.phasedescription + "</em>");

console.log(si);
```

Renders as:

```
undefined undefined undefined
Current Phase: undefined undefined
```

Thanks,
  - Greg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined `si` as an array, but are not indexing into that array when you are accessing the variable.

Remove the square brackets around the definition of `si` and you should be good to go.

Comment: No probs. Always good to help a fellow Greg. :-) And it's that time of day that such mistakes are all too understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `si` variable contains an array with one object (`[{}]`). The correct syntax would be `si[0].semestername` etc. Or you can leave out the array wrapper if you don't need it.